# How to resolve receiving 'TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null" error on function (reactjs)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

A TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null for this function" keeps appearing and I'm not sure where the problem comes from. Can anyone do the favor of showing how to resolve this issue? This is reactjs btw

```
import React from 'react';

function Electricity_Daily(){
    
    var energyKwh = document.getElementById('Your energy used up in Kwh').value; 
    var electricityDaily = parseInt(energyKwh) * .92;
    document.getElementById('co2 Emmissions Daily').value = electricityDaily;
};
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');

ReactDOM.render(<Electricity_Daily />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is trying to access the `value` property of something that doesn't exist ( `null`). You do this at `document.getElementById('Your energy used up in Kwh').value`. Simply put, the ElementId is not fond; The same thing is true two lines down (probably).

Simply put, we need more code to solve this (where you declare those IDs).